Issue with django-crispy-forms and django-filter: CSS class not applying to custom ChoiceFilter field
I'm using django-filter and django-crispy-forms to create a filter form in Django, but I'm having trouble applying a CSS class to a custom ChoiceFilter field. The CSS class is successfully applied to the date field but does not work for the transaction_type field, which is defined as a ChoiceFilter.
Here’s my current code:
filters.py
import django_filters
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field
from .models import Transaction

class TransactionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    transaction_type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES,
        field_name="type",
        lookup_expr="iexact",
        empty_label="Any",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['transaction_type', 'date']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.helper = FormHelper()
        self.form.helper.form_method = 'GET'

        self.form.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('transaction_type', css_class='MY-CLASS'),
            Field('date', css_class='MY-CLASS'),
        )

my view:
@login_required
def transactions_list(request):
    transactions_filter = TransactionFilter(
        request.GET,
        Transaction.objects.filter(user=request.user),
    )
    context = {'filter': transactions_filter}
    return render(request, 'tracker/transactions_list.html', context)

My template:
<form method="GET">
    <div class="mb-2 form-control">
        {% crispy filter.form %}
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success">
        Filter
    </button>
</form>

In this setup, I expected both fields to have the MY-CLASS CSS class, but only the date field reflects it, not transaction_type. I suspect this might be due to transaction_type being a custom ChoiceFilter field, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.
I've tried a few different approaches, such as updating widget attributes and applying CSS directly through attrs, but nothing has worked so far.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or have suggestions on how to force the CSS class to apply to the ChoiceFilter field?

Hope this helps.
ex:
import django_filters
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field
from django import forms
from .models import Transaction

class TransactionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    transaction_type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES,
        field_name="type",
        lookup_expr="iexact",
        empty_label="Any",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'MY-CLASS'}), 
    )
    date = django_filters.DateFilter(
        field_name='date',
        lookup_expr='exact',
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'MY-CLASS'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['transaction_type', 'date']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.helper = FormHelper()
        self.form.helper.form_method = 'GET'
        self.form.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('transaction_type', css_class='MY-CLASS'), 
            Field('date', css_class='MY-CLASS'),
        )


Thank you for your answer, but this is one of the solutions I tried, without success.

I hope this will work, or please share your expanded code to check further if not works.
